# Retrieve "View as a web page" URL link using API

Tags: marketing-cloud

The personalized email, that a recipient receives has a link to view the email as a web page. it is called `View as a web page` and links to `http://view.s4.exacttarget.com/?[someencryptevalues]`.

How do i retrieve this link using the `API`. I have the `SendID` and the `Recipient Email Address`. Using these two parameters, can i retrieve this URL.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would do this using the Sendlog.

You will need to add a field to your Sendlog called "view_email_url". Once this is done, add this code to your email AMPscript:

```
%%[ 
var @view_email_url
set @view_email_url = view_email_url 
]%%
```

As long as you have Sendlogging enabled for the send, the field should populate with the URL. You can then use the API to retrieve the Sendlog record.

If possible you should always try to match on JobID (SendID), SubscriberID and BatchID, otherwise you run the risk of returning multiple records for your retrieve request. For instance, if you have the same email address multiple times in one send. The risk of that is even higher for Triggered sends, since a new JobID is only generated when you publish.

Comment: I agree that a SendLog would be the way to go but the AMPScript mentioned is not required.  SendLog fields that match system variables will automatically be added to the send log. As long as the field in the sendlog is named exactly view_email_url then that will be logged.

Comment: One caveat to the no-script option that @Mac suggested...It only works for personalization strings that don't start with an underscore.  Strings like `_DataSourceName` can't be added as columns in a data extension.