# Marketing Cloud: Write "View As Web Page" link and subject of email in Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-views, marketingcloudapi

For our call center agents it is important to see the emails and its contents a subscriber has received. My idea is to provide our crm system with a file containing the subscriber id, the email subject line, the timestamp of send and the view as web page link.

In our crm system we would then match the subscriber id to our contact profiles and create a view showing the last emails that have been received by that contact (subject, timestamp, web page link).

My questions:

- How can I get the "View As Web Page" link for every mail every
  subscriber receives and write it in a data extension? Is there an easier solution
  than using the send log? (see
  [Retrieve "View as a web page" URL link using API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/30012/retrieve-view-as-a-web-page-url-link-using-api))
  Please note: I also want to do this for regular email sends.
- How can I get the subject linke for every mail every subscriber receives and
  write it in a data extension?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I am not sure that is best idea, because VAWP is dependent on the data still existing in the sending de and the AMPscript is rerun whenever opened, meaning that what is displayed will never be an exact duplicate of what was sent. Instead you might want to scrape the VAWP and save it as image or collect the processed HTML and store that elsewhere.

Comment: Well, I'm looking for a solution that is more or less possible to implement without any extra software. However, also scraping the content will lead to the problem, that I'll need to assign VAWP links to subscriber ids...